# jQuery code for automatic Increment the item depends on the date

Tags: php, css, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var theDialog = $(".mydialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto'
        });

        $('#one').click(function(){
            theDialog.html('some random text').dialog('open');
        });

        $('#two').click(function(){
            theDialog.html('<ul><li>Apple</li><li>Orange</li><li>Banana</li><li>Strawberry</li><li>long text string to see if width changes</li></ul>').dialog('open');
        });

        $('#three').click(function(){
            //this is only call where off-centre is noticeable so use setTimeout
            theDialog.html('<img src="./random.gif" width="500px" height="500px" />');
            setTimeout(function(){ theDialog.dialog('open') }, 100);;
        });
     });
</script>
```

hi friends i have  question, i have  an iteam, no of 20 i want to add 2 item daily with the total item automatic, i need the jquery code , anyone can help me plz?

Comment: This is extremely vague. What kinds of items do you have? Where do you want to add them? And you know the Javascript will run in a browser so the only way it can do anything daily is if the browser is kept open during those days?

Comment: i dont  know the javascript but i know how to use in html actually i want to add the cup of chai , i want to add its daily in 20 number